# Replacing XML element in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to replace the element inside of bbox with a new set of coordinates.

my code :

```
    # import element tree
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 


    #import xml file
    tree = ET.parse('C:/highway.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()

    #replace bounding box with new coordinates

    elem = tree.findall('bbox')
    elem.txt = '40.5,41.5,-12.0,-1.2'
```

my xml file:

```
   <geoEtl>
    <source>
        <server>localhost</server>
        <port>xxxx</port>
        <db>vxxx</db>
        <user>xxxx</user>
        <passwd>xxxx</passwd>
    </source>
    <targetDir>/home/firstuser/</targetDir>
    <bbox>-52.50,-1.9,52.45,-1.85</bbox>
    <extractions>
        <extraction>
            <table>geo_db_roads</table>
            <outputName>highways</outputName>
            <filter>highway = 'motorway'</filter>
            <geometry>way</geometry>
            <fields>
                <field>name</field>             
            </fields>
        </extraction>
    </extractions>
   </geoEtl>
```

have tried a variety of ways to do of things i found here but it doesnt seem to be working. thanks.

The error I'm receiving is as follows:

```
line 20, in <module> elem.txt = '40.5,41.5,-12.0,-1.2' AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'txt' –
```

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: line 20, in <module>
    elem.txt = '40.5,41.5,-12.0,-1.2'
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'txt'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) function, as the name implies, finds *all* matching elements, not just one.

So, after this:

```
elem = tree.findall('bbox')
```

`elem` is a list of `Element`s. And, as with any other list, this:

```
elem.txt = '40.5,41.5,-12.0,-1.2'
```

Is going to give you an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'txt'
```

If you want to do something to every member of a list, you have to loop over it:

```
elems = tree.findall('bbox')
for elem in elems:
    elem.txt = '40.5,41.5,-12.0,-1.2'
```

Comment: ok awesome it runs no problem now, should be it rewriting the new coordinates on my XML file or is that a different issue?

Comment: @Moggy: `ET.parse('C:/highway.xml')` just parses the file into a tree in memory. If you want to modify the XML file, you have to edit the tree, then _save it back to a file_`. You can do `tree.write('C:/highway.xml')` if you want to overwrite the original version with the new one.

Answer (score 3):

If your file isn't update it is most likely because you are not saving it, you can use the [`tree.write`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file) method to do just that.

```
tree.write('output.xml')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# import element tree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

#import xml file
tree = ET.parse('C:/highway.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

elems = root.findall(".//bbox")

for elem in elems:
    elem.text = '40.5,41.5,-12.0,-1.2'

tree.write('C:/highway.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the text of all boundingboxes with  '40.5,41.5,-12.0,-1.2', try this

```
bboxes = tree.xpath('//bbox')
for bbox in bboxes:
    bbox.text= '40.5,41.5,-12.0,-1.2'
```

Comment: i get AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'xpath'

Comment: Yes - sorry. I also had slightly simpler code for parsing - I used etree as my base class and etree includes the xpath function. I had assumed that ElementTree has that too but I never double-checked it

Comment: @kamjagin: There is no class called `etree` anywhere. In both the 2.x and 3.x stdlibs, `etree` is a package with nothing in it but the `ElementTree` module; in the separately-installable module from Fredrick Lundh's website, nothing at all has that name; in `lxml`, `etree` is a module with roughly the same API as `ElementTree` in the others. `Element` handles XPath syntax in the `findall` method; in the `lxml` implementation you can also call it as `xpath`, but you still call it on `Element`s, not an empty package that you've somehow used as a base class.